# jQuery Mobile: catch "finger down" event

Tags: events, event-handling, jquery-mobile, keypress

I need to detect the user "finger-press", there's already the "tap" event, but `tap = press + release`.

I need to call a JS function exactly on finger-press, exactly as `keypress()` does for standard browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of events for that already.

They are `vmousedown` and `taphold`.

You can find a complete reference about them at this link:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Basically, the jQuery Mobile framework maps the major "traditional" browser UI events prefixing them with a "v".

This is to signal that they are "virtual" events, in that by this mean you can catch events coming from standard (i.e. non-touch) and even touch-oriented devices as well.

So you could install a handler for a vmousedown event with:

```
$('#your-element-id').live('vmousedown', function() { alert("Hello") });
```

`taphold`, instead, is quite different: the event is triggered when a complete tap event takes place with a duration of nearly a second or more.

You can quickly play around with these two events to understand which one better fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like `taphold` or `vmousedown`?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: This is kind of a comment, maybe you can flesh-out your answer a bit more?

Comment: Sure, but I think Federico already did in his post. Thank you for your comment.